# Asp.net resource file to localize a web site: what to put in?

Tags: asp.net, resource-files

When we use resource file to localize a web site , we should put in the resource file also html tags in order to create less entries in the file?

```
this is <a href="www.alink.com" >a link<a>
```

or it is better to create two separe entry

```
 entry 1: this is



 entry 2: a link
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the first option, because the second relies on grammar and not all languages share the same grammatical structures.

For example, it's possible another language might need something like "a link this is", in which case option 2 will not work.

Comment: interesting answer, i agree with You: localization is not a mere traslation

Answer (score 0):

I think , you have to create key/value pair for each word, so it will help for reuse it.